# MySQL Pdo not returning message when row was found

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to prevent duplicate rows in my database with php.
I've been looking around on here. But most of the solutions do not work for me.
Since í'm quite the new shot at MySQL I can't really tell what i'm doing wrong.
the error_log does not report anything either.

Anyone willing to give me a hand on this?
Would be appreciated!

Code:

```
if ($command == 'support'){
    $query = $_GET['message'];

    $g = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `entry` WHERE message = '$query'");
    $g->execute();
    $result = $g->fetchObject();

    if ($result->total > 0){
        die('The same message was found in our database.');
    }

    if ($query > 150){
        die('Message can not be longer than 150 characters!');
    }

    if (empty($query)){
        die('No subject specified');
    }
    else{
        print('Query has been submitted.');

        var_dump($g);

        $querys = $odb ->query("INSERT INTO entry(message) VALUES ('$query')");

    }
}
```

Database file:

```
CREATE TABLE `entry` (
  `message` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: You need to give the column an alias to access it as `->total` - `SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM`

Comment: For the record: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the column an alias to access it as `->total`, with your existing code you will get a field called `COUNT(*)`.  So change your select to...

```
$g = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `entry` WHERE message = '$query'");
```

(also as mentioned, look into prepared statements and bind values ).

Also note that later where you do...

```
if ($query > 150){
```

is just checking if the value is greater than 150, should be

```
if (strlen($query) > 150){
```

I assume.

Comment: You also could change by a paramaterized query ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can check message is exist or not by counting the length of array return by the execute statement.
Try this code.

```
    $g = $odb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `entry` Where message =:message ");
$g->bindParam('message', $message);
$g->execute();
$rows = $g->fetchAll();
if(count($rows))
{
     die('The same message was found in our database.');
}
```